# ASP.NET Web Forms jQuery Update Progress without ASP.NET Update Panle or Script Manager

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, forms, web

On my contact page I have some validation under submit click. When submit button click I want to show update progress on my contact form. Can I do it without using Asp.net update panel or script manager.

Update panel and script manager load another 300KB. It makes the page slow.

What should I do?

I have used jQuery validation and after validation i have used the code below:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "", 
    data: "{}", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: "json", 
    async: true, 
    success: function (msg) { 
        $("#progressbar").html(""); 
        $("#result").text(msg.d); 
        clearInterval(intervalID); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: 300kb shouldn't make your page slow.  Also any examples or code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your situation sounds fairly standard, and I agree with jeschafe that 300k shouldn't cause any noticable slowdown.  I believe that using an update panel in this case is the correct choice, however you can write your own solution doing something like this:

Create a page method where you will perform your validation and use jQuery to serialize your form and make an ajax call to the page method ([Example Here](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)).  You can use a loading gif from a site like [this](http://ajaxload.info/) and display it while you are waiting for the response, if the validation process is going to take a while.

Comment: Hi Trey, Thank you very much for you quick reply. My jQuery code is below:

Comment: It looks like your code didn't make it.  You can try updating your question with it.

Comment: I have used jQuery validation and after validation i have used the code below:$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (msg) {
                       $("#progressbar").html("");
                       $("#result").text(msg.d);
                       clearInterval(intervalID);
                     }                    
                });

Comment: That's the right format.  You'll need to update the data and url properties with the proper information.